# Can I use PARTITIONED BY after the table has been created?

Tags: hive, hiveql

```
create table t1 as select * from t2 where 1=2;
```

I am using the above code to create a table t1 from table t2. In this table t2 is partitioned on 3 vaules, i.e. month, day, year. Once the table t1 is created it is not partitioned on the values mentioned above.

I have tried the below code but it is giving me errors. Help!

```
create table t1 as 
select * from t2 PARTITIONED BY( YEAR  STRING, MONTH STRING, DAY  STRING);
```

> [42000]: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'PARTITIONED' 'BY' '(' in table source

Answer (score 1):

Just need to correct the syntax. `partitioned by ...` goes after `create table`.

```
create table t1 PARTITIONED BY(YEAR STRING,MONTH STRING,DAY STRING) as 
select /*add other columns here*/,year,month,day 
from t2;
```

It is suggested to explicitly call out the columns instead of `*` and specify the partitioning columns towards the end of `select`.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is right, solution for creating partition at/during the time of table creation.

In-case table already created without partition, then one of ways is using INSERT OVERWRITE.

```
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict;

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE <table_name> PARTITION(<partition_name>) 
    SELECT <column_1,... column_n, partition_name> from <table_name>;
```